# Tileset background black? phaser

Tags: phaser-framework, tiled

I have made a map with Tiled.
[image: Created a map with Tiled]]

When I render the map on phaser i get this

[image: rendered map]]

It seems that the background of the tiles is not transparent.
I want to make the black background of the tiles to be green as the grass like they are in Tiled

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I want to make the black background of the tiles to be green as the grass

Comment: Like they are in tiled

Comment: I don't know if that makes sense, but have you tried setting stage background color as the color of the grass? `game.stage.backgroundColor = '#xxxxxx';`

Comment: Yes I tried but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution.
I have just changed the color of the tilesets from transparent to green as the grass [my tileset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICKS5.png)